# I need help to put URL in JavaScript code in framework codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

```
$.ajax({
    url:"....???.....",
    method:"POST",
    data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
    success:function(data)
    {
        $('#order_table').html(data);
    }
});
}
else
{
    alert("Please Select Date");
}
```

Comment: What is the controller and method that will handle the ajax request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url()?>';
```

use this base_url in your ajax function url like:

```
$.ajax({
   url : base_url + 'Controller/method',
   // do more
```